# RegEx for quoted string with missing open parenthesis

Tags: regex

What is RegEx for find quoted string having only close parenthesis at the end, like this :

```
"People)"
```

But not

```
"(People)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like so: `"[^(]+?\)"` should fit the bill. You might also need to escape the quotation marks and the backslash as well, depending on what regex engine you are using.

Some details on how does this regex work are available [here](http://regex101.com/r/wA6sW4).

Comment: Thanks, and if two consecutive lines have quotes, like this: "(ok)"
"not ok)", how can I say find just one quotation mark?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the following ?

String REGEX_TEST_STRING="\"People)\"";
System.out.println(REGEX_TEST_STRING.matches("\"P.*\)\""));

This code returns true for "People)" and false for "(People)"

HTH.